# Validation method returns true not false

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-validate

I am creating a jQuery validation method which I use on two dimension fields (width and height). The user can choose to use millimeters or inches in a select box on the page. The fields are validating the following points:

- Max. 980mm
- Min. 100mm
- If one of the two field is more than 860mm the other may not be more
  than 860mm.

**How it works:**
When a field is in use, an ajax call will be done with the value of the field. The value goes into a PHP function which converts it to the size in millimeters. This gives the right results in millimeters back.

When this value (in millimeters) comes back, It goes trough some conditional statements to check the validating point. Then a result variable gets set to true or false and at the end the script returns it.

**The problem:**
When I have set my size to "inches", and I fill in the first field with 38 (965,19mm) and the second field also to 38, the script returns true. This should not happen because my if statement say that if one field is more than 860mm the other may not be more than 860mm. The strange thing is that with using millimeters as size, everything goes right..

**My Javascript:**

```
/** Dimension restrictions validator method */
jQuery.validator.addMethod( 'restrictions', function(value, element) {

    // Set variables
    var result = true;
    var message = '';
    var other = $(element).parents().siblings('.input-group').find('.dimension-field').val();   
    var mUnit = $('#size_data option:selected').val(); 

    // Do ajax call to get millimeters
    $.ajax({
        url: sbt.ajaxurl,
        async: false,
        data: { action: 'sbt_mm_value', value: value, mu: mUnit },
        success: function(data) {

            // Smaller than 980
            if(data <= 980) {

                // Bigger than 100                                  
                if(data >= 100) {
                    result = true;
                } else {
                    result = false;

                    if(mUnit == 'in') {
                        message = sbt.msg.restrictions.minimum + ' 3.93in';
                    } else {
                        message = sbt.msg.restrictions.minimum + ' 100mm';
                    }
                }

                // Bigger than 860
                if(data > 860) {

                    // Other field smaller than or equal than 860
                    if(other <= 860) {
                        result = true;
                    } else {
                        result = false;
                        if(mUnit == 'in') {
                            message = sbt.msg.restrictions.maximum + ' 33.85in';    
                        } else {
                            message = sbt.msg.restrictions.maximum + ' 860mm';  
                        }
                    }
                } 

                // Smaller than or equal to 860
                if(data <= 860) {

                    // Other field smaller than or equal than 980
                    if(other <= 980) {
                        result = true;  
                    } else {
                        result = false;
                        if(mUnit == 'in') {
                            message = sbt.msg.restrictions.maximum + ' 33.85in';    
                        } else {
                            message = sbt.msg.restrictions.maximum + ' 860mm';  
                        }
                    }
                }

            } else {
                result = false;
                if(mUnit == 'in') {
                    message = sbt.msg.restrictions.maximum + ' 38.58in';    
                } else {
                    message = sbt.msg.restrictions.maximum + ' 980mm';  
                }
            }


        }
    });

    // Set message
    $.validator.messages.restrictions = message;

    // Return true or false
    return result;

});
```

**Applying the method to the fields:**

```
$('#action_form').validate({
    rules: {
        width_data: { 
            required: true,
            restrictions: true,

        },
        height_data: { 
            required: true,
            restrictions: true,
        },
    },
});
```

Comment: Your question is very unclear.  You are explaining that the value can be entered in inches, but your conditional logic is only setup to compare this entered value to various numbers that are represented by `mm`.  I see nothing here that does any English/metric conversions... so how can you expect this work?

Comment: Obviously, if it's working perfectly fine when you enter the value as `mm`, then there is nothing wrong with the code you've shown us.  You'll need to show us the server-side code as that's apparently where your failed logic is located.

Comment: @Sparky In my question I explain that if someone choose to use inches, the inches value, together with the selected size (which is inch then) are send with an AJAX call to a PHP function. This PHP function converts it to the mm value (which is 25.4 for inch). Then I always calculate with mm, but I need to show error messages for inches if inch is the selected size. In my problem section I explain what is going wrong when inch is selected as size and that it is going right with mm as selected size.

Comment: @Sparky I have found the solution. Check my answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution by myself. The problem was caused by the fact that the other field value not was converted to millimeters. This is why it worked with millimeters selected as size and not with inches, because millimeters where already millimeters, but inches not.

```
/** Dimension restrictions validator method */
jQuery.validator.addMethod( 'restrictions', function(value, element) {

    // Gets selected size
    var mUnit   = $('#size_data option:selected').val(); 

    // Gets values of both fields
    var otherField  = $(element).parents().siblings('.input-group').find('.dimension-field').val().toString();  
    var thisField   = value.toString();

    // Set default variables
    var result  = true;
    var message     = '';

    /** Does AJAX call to get millimeters and does checks */
    $.ajax({
        url: sbt.ajaxurl,
        async: false,
        data: { action: 'sbt_mm_value', mu: mUnit },
        success: function(data) {

            // Gets one unit in millimeters
            var multiply = data.toString();

            // Get millimeter values
            var value = thisField * multiply;
            var other = otherField * multiply;

            //console.log('Value = ' + value + ' and other is '+ other);

            // Smaller than 980
            if(value <= 980) {

                // Greater than 100                                 
                if(value >= 100) {
                    result = true;
                } else {
                    result = false;

                    if(mUnit == 'in') {
                        message = sbt.msg.restrictions.minimum + ' 3.93in';
                    } else {
                        message = sbt.msg.restrictions.minimum + ' 100mm';
                    }
                }

                // Greater than 860
                if(value > 860) {

                    // Other field smaller than or equal than 860
                    if(other <= 860) {
                        result = true;
                    } else {
                        result = false;
                        if(mUnit == 'in') {
                            message = sbt.msg.restrictions.maximum + ' 33.85in';    
                        } else {
                            message = sbt.msg.restrictions.maximum + ' 860mm';  
                        }
                    }
                } 

                // Smaller than or equal to 860
                if(value <= 860) {

                    // Other field smaller than or equal than 980
                    if(other <= 980) {
                        result = true;  
                    } else {
                        result = false;
                        if(mUnit == 'in') {
                            message = sbt.msg.restrictions.maximum + ' 33.85in';    
                        } else {
                            message = sbt.msg.restrictions.maximum + ' 860mm';  
                        }
                    }
                }

            } else {
                result = false;
                if(mUnit == 'in') {
                    message = sbt.msg.restrictions.maximum + ' 38.58in';    
                } else {
                    message = sbt.msg.restrictions.maximum + ' 980mm';  
                }
            }


        }
    });

    // Set message
    $.validator.messages.restrictions = message;

    // Return true or false
    return result;

});
```